# Install mapbox-gl package via jspm failing

Tags: aurelia, jspm, mapbox-gl

I am trying to add the mapbox gl package to my [Aurealia Typescript skeleton](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/tree/master/skeleton-typescript) using `jspm`. I am using the following command.

`jspm install npm:mapbox-gl`

This is what I am getting.

```
Looking up npm:mapbox-gl
Updating registry cache...
Downloading npm:mapbox-gl@0.19.1

warn Error on processPackageConfig
     Package.json dependency mapbox-gl-shaders set to github:mapbox/mapbox-gl-shaders#e4737bb136d718f9c5fe8d943380f05db6249b57, which is not a valid dependency format for npm.
     It's advisable to publish jspm-style packages to GitHub or another registry so conventions are clear.

warn Error processing package config for npm:mapbox-gl.

err  Error processing package config for npm:mapbox-gl.

warn Installation changes not saved.
```

I am using `jspm 0.16.36`.

When I try to install the package via `npm install mapbox-gl` it works normally. Any suggestions?

Comment: You're likely going to need a shim config for this to work. Search the jspm documentation on how to create and test this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you are using jspm, you might also want to try and reference it through the GitHub repo rather than through npm:

```
$ jspm install github:mapbox/mapbox-gl-js
```

It works for me with jspm v16.x and [v0.21.0 of MapboxGL](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/releases).